# Copy files with scss extension to the same paths in to dist folder

Tags: node.js

How can I copy all files with `*.scss` extension in to same paths from `srs/` folder to `dist/` with Node JS?

I tried `fs.copyFile('./src/**/*.scss', './src')`, but this is doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, this is just didn't copy files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly to say, but Node doesn't support copying of files using globs pattern.

Try this package instead: [cpx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx)